# Create a simple project android ros on windows

Tags: ros, android-core, gradle, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the how to
Android - Tutorials - hydro - Installation - Android Studio Development Environment

However the gradle can not build a project.

Environment
Windows 7
Android 0.4.0 Studio
Gradle 1.10
Android API 19

After create a project a apply modifications in bluid.gradle in my subproject. This is the content of the file:

I put spaces in url bacese my karma is insufficient to publish links

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'h t t p s : / / github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
     }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'h t t p s : / / github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
   compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+'
    //  compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'
    compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+'
}
```

When a "Rebluid the project"

Warning (33 items) of

Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

And this error:

Execution failed for task ':brain:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> C:\Desenvolvimento\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Bernardo\SkyDrive\www\arduino\ros\TheLorem-Brain\brain\build\pre-dexed\debug\xml-apis-1.0.b2-99724b73c87f7d301ef14642ea9d40f15a7c68ba.jar C:\Users\Bernardo.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\3136ca936f64c9d68529f048c2618bd356bf85c9\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
> Error Code:
> 1
> Output:
> trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
> when not building a core library.
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
> in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
> Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
> core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
> going on.
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
> namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
> from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
> assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
> compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
> It is also often of questionable legality.
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
> appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
> distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
> the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
> building an application, then be forewarned that your application
> will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
> prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
> application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
> system. You will be to blame for this problem.
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
> core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
> repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
> your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
> conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
> you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
> that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
> lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
> 1 error; aborting

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114046/create-a-simple-project-android-ros-on-windows/) by [Bernardo Silva](https://answers.ros.org/users/10336/bernardo-silva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I posted a similar question here http://answers.ros.org/question/114996/error-while-run-all-tests-in-a-simple-android-ros-project-in-ubuntu/

The configuration are basically the same except I am using Ubuntu.

I solved my problem by using

```
compile('org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'){
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'xml-apis'
    }
```

instead of

```
compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'
```

in your case, try

```
compile('org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+'){
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'xml-apis'
    }
compile('org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'){
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'xml-apis'
    }
```

hope it works for you.

---

Originally posted by [Lunbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/9381/lunbo/) with karma: 93 on 2014-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2